# PHP File upload XMLHttpRequest passing

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Im using XMLHttpRequest to upload a file to a php script. The problem is i cant change the file name from the client side and im struggling to work out how to send a variable **with** the file.

I have a textbox on the screen and basically when the user submits the file, i want the text from the textbox to go to the php file aswel.

Here is my upload function:

```
 function uploadFile() {

    var fd = new FormData();

          var count = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files.length;

          for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++)

          {

                 var file = document.getElementById('fileToUpload').files[index];

                 fd.append('myFile', file);


          }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false);

    xhr.open("POST", "savetofile.php");

    xhr.send(fd);

  }
```

and in the php file :

```
<?php
if (isset($_FILES['myFile'])) {

   // $text = contents of the textbox that has been sent from javascript

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'], "daa_coke/images/" . $_FILES['myFile']['name']);
   $xml = simplexml_load_file('daa_coke/newcoke.xml');
$employee = $xml->addChild('flight');
$employee->addChild('to', 'dsd');
$employee->addChild('from', 'Gary');
$employee->addChild('imagepath', $_FILES['myFile']['name']);
$employee->addChild('templateStyle', 'template1');
$employee->addChild('time', '13:37');
$employee->addChild('date', '24/12/16');

file_put_contents('daa_coke/newcoke.xml', $xml->asXML());


}
?>
```

I just want to be able to pass the contents of the textbox so i canput it in the $test variable.

Comment: just do another append ... `fd.append('textBoxName', textBoxValue)`

Comment: I have tried that and its not adding anything

Answer (score 0):

The `filename` should be third parameter passed to `.append()`

```
formData.append(name, value, filename);
```

e.g.;

```
fd.append("myFile", file, this.querySelector("input[type=text]").value);
```

See [`FormData.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Answer (score 0):

fd.append('textBoxName', textBoxValue) worked